# Backup one internal drive to another internal drive

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 that came preinstalled with Windows 8.1. I decided to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows and till the last week it was working perfectly. But, since yesterday I am unable to use Windows as it is really slow. However, Ubuntu works fine and smooth. I ran the Dell ePSA test and got a 2000-0142 error code, which is indicative of a hard-drive failure. So, if my HDD has really failed or is about to fail, how can I backup everything onto an external drive. Note that my Ubuntu and Windows are installed on the same drive and I am unable to use Windows.

EDIT: Contacted Dell, product is in warranty and they are giving me a new internal HDD. So the question is how can I backup my current drive to the new one, i.e, data from current hard drive to the new one that I'll get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that your original disk was failing I would recommend against dumping the old disk to the new one. I would just copy the files that I need from the old one and that's that.

---

*If you still want to copy the old drive to the new one this is what I would do:*

1. Connect both disks at the same time to the same computer
2. Boot with an Ubunutu CD/DVD
3. Find out which drive is the old one and which one is the new one. Probably one will be /dev/sda and the other will be /dev/sdb. YOU MUST CHECK THIS properly or you will risk erasing all your data.
4. Open a console and type this command (**change /dev/sda and /dev/sdb to where your disks are; this example assumes that sda is the old disk and sdb is the new drive**):

   ```
   dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K of=/dev/hda
   ```

---

*If you cannot connect both drives at the same time, you will need an external drive (or network drive) where you will store the disk image:*

1. Boot with an Ubunutu CD/DVD
2. Connect the external drive/network drive
3. Find out which drive is the old one and what folder is the external drive mounted to. Probably the drive will be /dev/sda and the other will be something like /media/user/XXXXXX. YOU MUST CHECK THIS properly or you will risk erasing all your data.
4. To make the backup open a console and type these commands (**change /dev/sda and /media/user/XXXXXX to where your disks are; this example assumes that sda is the old disk and /media/user/XXXXXX is a mounted backup directory**):

   ```
   dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /media/user/XXXXXX/sda.img.gz

   fdisk -l /dev/sda > /media/user/XXXXXX/sda_fdisk.info
   ```
5. Remove the old disk and plug the new one in, boot to an Ubuntu CD/DVD and enter this command:

   ```
   gunzip -c /media/user/XXXXXX/sda.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K
   ```

File /media/user/XXXXXX/sda_fdisk.info will contain some interesting information, such as cylinder size, etc, in case you need them.

You can see more information regarding this issue here:
http://debianhelp.co.uk/ddcommand.htm

Comment: One question, how will I connect my internal HDD via USB?

Comment: Usually you connect to a network drive in another computer on your network. If this is not a valid solution for you, you'll have to buy an adapter to connect your drive via eSATA, USB, etc.

A few examples:
http://www.moddiy.com/product_images/b/372/sata-usb__32258_zoom.jpg
or
http://www.locoisle.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/5e06319eda06f020e43594a9c230972d/f/i/file_413_45.jpg

Comment: Don't forget to double(triple)-check that you are not erasing the wrong disk at any moment. Glad I could help.

Comment: Excellent answer!  An edit (you need 4 additional spaces if using `commands` and numbers at the same time) *and* an upvote! ;-)
@XZYoda12: as your drive is failing, use `ddrescue` instead of `dd`

Comment: @Fabby, the drive in question is dead(R.I.P).

Comment: I hope you got a decent back-up before it did!  (you got a lot of advance warning...)  ;-)